# Evaluating $ \int_0^\pi \frac{\cos{n\theta}}{1 -2r\cos{\theta}+r^2} d\theta $

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration, complex-integration

How do I go about evaluating the following integral:

$$ \int_0^\pi \frac{\cos{n\theta}}{1 -2r\cos{\theta}+r^2} d\theta $$

for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and  $r \in (0,1)$?

My trick has been to rewrite, using the exponential form of $\cos$, as:

$$ \int_0^\pi  \frac{e^{ni\theta} + e^{-ni\theta}}{2(1 - re^{i\theta})(1-re^{-i\theta})} d\theta.$$

Letting $z = e^{i\theta}$ and $d\theta = \frac{1}{iz}dz$, we get

$$ \frac{1}{2i}\int_{|z|=1}  \frac{z^n + \frac{1}{z}^n}{(1 - rz)(z-r)} d\theta $$

This would have a singularity when $z= e^{i\theta} = r$  or when $zr = re^{i \theta} = 1$. Since $r \in (0,1)$ neither of these can occur. So we just need to integrate the above, but I can't see any way about this?

Is my approach valid or along the right lines, and how can I proceed?

Comment: I also see a singularity in $0$...

Comment: @N74 Does this not require $r=1$? The integrand becomes $\frac{1}{1 -2r + r^2}$, so we solve $1 -2r + r^2=0$ so $r=1$ but $r \in (0,1)$?

Comment: if $r \ne 1$ one of  $\frac {1}{1-rz}$ or $\frac {1}{z-r}$ has a singularity on the disk or radius $1.$ (i.e. inside the contour)  and as @N74 points out, there is a pole at 0 to consider, as well.

Comment: @DougM Ahh I see where I was missing the singularities for $\frac{1}{1-rz}$ and $\frac{1/{z-r}$, I was only looking for ones on the boundary but needed to find ones in the disc. Could you explain how 0 is a pole though, I can't see it?

Comment: you have $\frac {1}{z^n}$ in the numerator, creating a pole.

Comment: @DougM Of course! Thanks! So is it now a case of *just* calculating the residues around each of these poles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The contour integration way:**

Residue theorem reveals *within a second* that

$$\int_0^\pi \frac{\cos{n\theta}}{1 -2r\cos{\theta}+r^2} d\theta=\pi\frac{r^n}{1-r^2}.$$

**Note:** To make everything simpler (compared with what you tried in your post) it is enough to use in the numerator $e^{i n\theta}$.

**The real method way**:

Exploit *carefully* the well-known series result (which can be proved by real methods)

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} p^n \sin(n x)=\frac{p\sin(x)}{1-2 p \cos(x)+p^2}, |p|<1$$

Comment: Can you expand on "within a second"?  It really doesn't seem quick to me (unless there is some other method?)

Comment: @Sergestus read the note above.

Comment: Ahh taking that, we no longer have the residue at $z=0$ right? And then the residue at $z=r$ gives the required (and I see now how it should have been within seconds!) But why is taking only $e^{in\theta}$ valid?

Comment: @Sergestus right! In general you'll find useful for such integrals to use Euler's formula here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula. In our case, that's the real part you're interested in.

Comment: That clears everything up, thanks for your answers!

Comment: @Sergestus welcome!

Comment: I am unable to understand how to proceed with the residue way?

Answer (score 1):

The given integral is $I=\frac12\Re(J)$ where $J=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{in\theta}}{1-2r\cos\theta+r^2}d\theta$. As OP did, we substitute $z=e^{i\theta}$ to get, for $r>1$,
$$J=\frac{i}{r}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{z^n}{(z-r)(z-\frac1r)}=\frac{i}{r}2\pi i\left(Res_{z=\frac1r}\frac{z^n}{(z-r)(z-\frac1r)}\right)=-\frac{2\pi} r\frac{r^{-n}}{\frac1r-r}=\frac{2r^{-n}}{r^2-1}\pi.$$
Hence, $J$ is real and $I=\frac12J=\frac{r^{-n}}{r^2-1}\pi.$

Example: $n=2$ and $r=5$. Then $I=\frac{5^{-2}}{5^2-1}\pi=\frac{\pi}{600}$ which is in [agreement with WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int_0%5E%28pi%29%20cos%282x%29%2F%281-10cosx%2B25%29dx).

For $r\in(0,1)$, we take the other root and get $I=\large\frac{r^{n}}{1-r^2}\pi.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be some function analytic in some region containing the unit disc $|z|\le1$. Then due to [Poisson integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel), it is true for $0\le r<1$ that

$$
\Re[f(re^{i\phi})]={1\over2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi{1-r^2\over1-2r\cos(\theta-\phi)+r^2}f(e^{i\theta})\mathrm d\theta.
$$

Let $f(z)=z^n$ and $\phi=0$, so we have

$$
{r^n\over1-r^2}={1\over2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi{\cos(n\theta)\over1-2r\cos(\theta)+r^2}\mathrm d\theta=\frac1\pi\int_0^\pi{\cos(n\theta)\over1-2r\cos(\theta)+r^2}\mathrm d\theta.
$$