# Don't understand the answer of $\int_0^\pi \frac{\cos{n\theta}}{1 -2r\cos{\theta}+r^2} d\theta$

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I don't understand the answer provided in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2772746/evaluating-int-0-pi-frac-cosn-theta1-2r-cos-thetar2-d-theta), what does "to use in the numerator $e^{inθ}$" mean? Also, how to handle the upper limit $\pi$ instead of $2\pi$? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Based on how the OP of that post did their attempt, they used the complex definition of $\cos\theta$, and it seems like the answerer is saying it's easier to use $\Re e^{in\theta} = \cos\theta$ so that $\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\cos\left(n\theta\right)}{1-2r\cos\theta+r^{2}}d\theta = \Re\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{e^{in\theta}}{1-2r\cos\theta+r^{2}}d\theta$ instead. Also, $\Re\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{e^{in\theta}}{1-2r\cos\theta+r^{2}}d\theta = \frac{1}{2}\Re\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{in\theta}}{1-2r\cos\theta+r^{2}}d\theta$.

Comment: @Accelerator How do you prove $\Re\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{e^{in\theta}}{1-2r\cos\theta+r^{2}}d\theta = \frac{1}{2}\Re\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{in\theta}}{1-2r\cos\theta+r^{2}}d\theta$? Direct subsititution doesnt seem to work, I first prove $\int_{-\pi}^{0}=\int_{0}^{\pi}$ and argue $\int_{-\pi}^{0}=\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}$ because of periodicity.

Comment: Since you already know that $\int_{-\pi}^{0}=\int_{0}^{\pi}$ and $\int_{-\pi}^{0}+\int_{0}^{\pi}=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \implies 2\int_{0}^{\pi}=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}$, you can use (or prove if you want) the fact that the integrand is periodic on $2\pi$, which means $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}$. Can you finish?

Comment: @Accelerator I apologize for my misleading question. I should have been asking is there a shorter way, eg how to do this by direct substitution?

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted to do the periodicity thing. I don't know of a way to handle it by one mere substitution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $e^{iz}=\cos z+i\sin z$, you have:
$$\cos z=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}\quad\quad (*) $$
Using $(*)$, the numerator becomes:
$$\cos n\theta=\frac{e^{in\theta}+e^{-in\theta}}{2} $$
Now, consider the denominator:
$$ 1-2r\cos \theta+r^2=1-r(e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta})+r^2=e^{i\theta} e^{-i\theta}-re^{i\theta}-r e^{-i\theta}+r^2=\\ (e^{i\theta} -r)(e^{-i\theta}-r)=(e^{i\theta} -r)\left(\frac{1-re^{i\theta}}{e^{i\theta}}\right)=(1-re^{-i\theta})(1-re^{i\theta})$$

Comment: Do you subsititute it into $\int_0^\pi  \frac{e^{ni\theta} + e^{-ni\theta}}{2(1 - re^{i\theta})(1-re^{-i\theta})} d\theta$ or $\int_0^\pi  \frac{e^{ni\theta}}{2(1 - re^{i\theta})(1-re^{-i\theta})} d\theta$? I suppose the integral could be the real part of the later?

Comment: I would be grateful if you could provide a more detailed solution

Comment: @HIH sure, let me edit the post to add details

Comment: Now I understand, thank you so much!